# Add class to parent li if NavLink is active

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I need to add a class to the parent `<li>` tag of a NavLink when the NavLink is active, however I struggle to find out how to do so especially since there exists no CSS selector to select parent elements, and apparently NavLink does not expose any `IsActive` property. My code is:

```
<li>
    <NavLink href="@Url">
        @Text
    </NavLink>
</li>
```

And my css

```
li.some-class-needing-to-be-set < a.active {
    property: value;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried in my side to try an easy solution but indeed it seems that NavLink does not have an easy way to get if it is Active or not.

I found this code example: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/navbar+change+active+class+link+blazor

I think it could be the good solution for you, with some small modifications. If you need any help to do so, do not hesitate, I'll be glad to try to help you.

Comment: Indeed, thanks a lot for the idea! This will be my B plan.

Comment: This is the approach I ended up using since the built-in components do not expose the necessary APIs at this time. Thank you again for helping me!

Comment: You're welcome, I hope it was not too hard to adapt! See you